# What do the new blue and orange symbols mean in the multiplayer lobby?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've noticed some new additions to the UI in the multiplayer lobby since the last patch (pictured below). Instead of just showing a player's N7 rating, it sometimes cycles through two other numbers. What do they mean?

[image: Screenshot showing the blue symbol]
[image: Screenshot showing the orange symbol]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The number with a blue background indicates the number of times that you've promoted your currently selected class.** It will only appear if you've promoted that class at least once.

**The number with an orange background is the amount of Challenge Points you've earned.** The 1.04 patch introduced a new system where players earn Challenge Points for completing milestones (such as obtaining a certain number points while using a specific weapon). Each milestone completed will award the player some Challenge points, and the sum of these points is shown next to the trophy icon. See [this blog post](http://blog.bioware.com/2012/10/08/developer-blog-updates-coming-to-me3-multiplayer/) for more information about Challenges.